# Program to find how many words in a text don't contain a specific character

Tags: c, string, search

The following program runs without printing anything on the screen, maybe because the loop goes over the null character. I can't understand why and how this happens, and how to fix it.

```
//program to find how many word in the text doesn't contain p char

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define space ' '

void find_word(char s[]) {
  bool wordfound = false;

  int i, j = 0, word = 0;
  i = 0;

  while (s[i]) { //s[i]!='\0'  does not

    if (s[i] != 'p' && s[i + 1] != space) { //for the first word 
      wordfound = true;
      word++;
    }

    wordfound = false;

    if (s[i] == space && s[i + 1] != space) { //for more than one word in the text 
      for (j = i + 1; s[j] != space; j++)
        if (s[j] != 'p' && s[j + 1] != space)
          wordfound = true;
    }
    if (wordfound) {
      word++;
    }
    wordfound = false;
    i = j;
    i++;
  } //end while loop

  printf("Number of words not contain p character%d\n\n", word);

}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = {"pppp zzzz ppp ssss dfg sfsfdsf"};
  find_word(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding : 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4)  please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: you might want to look into the header file: `ctypes.h`  especially the `isspace()` and `ispunc()`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Number of words not contain p character%d",word);`  this will leave the data in the `stdout` buffer until the program exits.  To have it immediately displayed on the terminal, end the format string with '\n' (a new line) as that will flush the `stdout` buffer to the terminal

Comment: regarding:  `if ( s[i]!='p' && s[i+1] != space )
   wordfound = true;
   
  if(wordfound)
   word++;
   
  wordfound= false;` this can be condensed to:  `if ( s[i]!='p' && s[i+1] != space )
   word++;`

Comment: regarding: `for( j=i+1; s[j] != space; i++ )`  perhaps you meant: `for( j=i+1; s[j] != space; j++ )`  such that the variable `j` is being incremented

Comment: to help you (and any other readers of your code) to understand the logic of your code, always include the optional braces '{' and '}'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: insert an appropriate space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside braces, around C operators

Comment: @user3629249 I was thinking we only need /n in old complies  but even after I add /n it still doenst print anything

Comment: `if (s[i] == space && s[i + 1] != space) { 
      for (j = i + 1; s[j] != space; j++) if (s[j] != 'p' && s[j + 1] != space)` is a problem when `s[i + 1]` is a _null character_.   Inner loop attempts access outside string.  This inner `j` loop appears to run on and on in other cases too.

Comment: @user3629249 yes this was a mistake but it  still give a black screen

Comment: @user3629249 yes I think its good idea to use library function but applied in this code calling a function each time in nested loop  maybe  a bad idea     what do think its the better way to do it with  a library function

Comment: Jassim Alsokni, the "word" detection is weak.  Consider `"no_spaces"`, `" leading_spaces"`, `"trailing_spaces "`, `"  "`, `""`.  Get your word count to work in such cases, then amend code to look for `'p'`.  [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm)

Comment: @JassimAlsokni,  Since the posted code never ends, it never executes the  call to `printf()`, so, of course, it never prints anything

Comment: @JassimAlsokni,  the `isspace()` and etc are not functions (usually) rather, they are macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code, but the main one is that inside the loop you assign **j** to **i** which causes the infinite loop as the **while(s[i])** condition is never met. Why don't you try to make it simple, like so:

```
//program to find how many word in the text doesn't contain p char

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define space ' '

void find_word(char s[]) {
  bool is_in = false;
  short words_count = 0, i = 0; 

  while (s[i]) {
      if (s[i] == 'p') { // if this letter is a 'p', mark the word
          is_in = true;
      }

      if (s[i] == space) { // if it's end of word
          if (!is_in) { // check if 'p' is present and increase the count
              words_count++;
          }
          is_in = false;
      }

      i++;
  }

  if (!is_in) { // check if the last word has 'p'
      words_count++;
  }

  printf("no. of words without p is %d\n", words_count);

}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = {"pppp zzzz ppp ssss dfg sfsfdsf"};
  find_word(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have your `for-loop` terminating condition set to be unsatisfiable given your input.

```
if (s[i] == space && s[i + 1] != space) { //for more than one word in the text 
  for (j = i + 1; s[j] != space; j++)
    if (s[j] != 'p' && s[j + 1] != space)
      wordfound = true;
}
```

Here you are checking for a leading space in your input string.  If you find it you then increment your index checking until you reach another space.  What if your string doesn't have a trailing space?

Instead try to have a second condition for null *and* space to terminate the loop:

```
if (s[i] == space && s[i + 1] != space) { //for more than one word in the text 
  for (j = i + 1; s[j] != '\0' && [j] != space; j++)
    if (s[j] != 'p' && s[j + 1] != space)
      wordfound = true;
}
```

And then you set:

```
    wordfound = false;
    i = j;
    i++;
  } //end while loop
```

This will keep re-setting your loop, I'm not clear on your reasoning for this but that will run your loop indefinitely.

If you make these edits your code terminates:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define space ' '

void find_word(char s[]) {
  bool wordfound = false;

  int i, j = 0, word = 0;
  i = 0;

  while (s[i]) { //s[i]!='\0'  does not

    if (s[i] != 'p' && s[i + 1] != space) { //for the first word 
      wordfound = true;
      word++;
    }

    wordfound = false;

    if (s[i] == space && s[i + 1] != space) { //for more than one word in the text 
      for (j = i + 1; s[j] && s[j] != space; j++)
        if (s[j] != 'p' && s[j + 1] != space)
          wordfound = true;
    }
    if (wordfound) {
      word++;
    }
    wordfound = false;
    i++;
  } //end while loop

  printf("Number of words not contain p character%d\n\n", word);

}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = {"pppp zzzz ppp ssss dfg sfsfdsf"};
  find_word(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number of words not contain p character24
```